# How is Windows 10 auto tagging concepts/activities in my photos, and how do I disable?

Tags: windows-10, privacy, photos

I've just noticed that Windows 10 has created automatic collections of some of my photos. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1062339/why-did-the-photos-app-auto-create-a-random-photo-album?newreg=8559ad3565e54c5db115b5e2f0760379) covered it creating albums (maybe just a semantic difference?) based on date/time which is somewhat understandable.

But one collection is called "Happy days" with a subtitle "#smile" - presumably based on facial analysis.
Another photo containing someone wearing some protective equipment on their face was tagged "Scuba diving" - a plausible error in AI recognition.

Is it uploading all my photos to Microsoft to do this? I can't see any reference to this online, with the exception of OneDrive folders, which this is not!

How can I disable it?

Comment: Are you automatically uploading photos to OneDrive?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I've never used OneDrive elsewhere, and starting the OneDrive app on this machine asks me to sign in and setup OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

The AI engine for this appears to run locally on your device, and store the additional metadata in a file that you can find at `%USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\MediaDb.v1.sqlite` (which is why the tags will sometimes differ if you are synchronising photos via OneDrive).